# How do I "pass through" the inherited properties of Control and ContentControl to an element in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPF question.  I'm not sure what to google for.

I have a usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.MyControl"
             x:Name="Self"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button />
</UserControl>
```

I use it like this:

```
<local:MyControl Background="Green" />
```

But the background doesn't seem to change.  It's because the background of the button hasn't changed.  I want the background of the button to use the background of the usercontrol.

I suppose I could do this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.MyControl"
             x:Name="Self"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=Self" />
</UserControl>
```

But I pretty much want all of the inherited properties from Control and ContentControl to apply to the button (ToolTip, BorderThickness, BorderBrush, etc).

So what can I do instead of this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.MyControl"
             x:Name="Self"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=Self"
            ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip, ElementName=Self"
            BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, ElementName=Self"
            BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, ElementName=Self"
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ... />
</UserControl>
```

?

(Note: This is a small (the smallest I could manage, in fact) example of a larger UserControl which hosts many controls.)

Comment: If all you do is host one button, then why don't you insert that into your other XAML directly? Otherwise when your hosting more controls (as is usually the case) you have to do it as in your example, because controls are, as you know, lookless.

Comment: This is a small (the smallest I could manage, in fact) example of a larger UserControl which hosts many controls.

Comment: Does it need to be a UserControl? Why not just a Style Template or ContentControl with your Dependencies brought through with TemplateBindings?

Comment: These sound like interesting solutions.  I'm new to WPF and will google these keywords.  Please feel free to elaborate in an Answer, though!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Well, short answer: You can't, at least not easily. XAML doesn't work quite like HTML/CSS does. The `Button` (and for that matter, pretty much any `Control`) does not inherit properties from their containers by default.

You *could* craft your own `Button`, etc controls that do inherit...alternatively, you might be able to declare a `Style` that applies to everything and attempts to grab any containing elements properties (i.e., via `RelativeSource FindAncestor`)...or you could do what you're doing here: set every property manually.

Example of the `Style` approach:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter 
        Property="Background" 
        Value="{Binding (Control.Background), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Which one of JerKimball's three solutions are you referring to?

Comment: Likely the Style approach, since I didn't really get into the other ones (I'm lazy, and that'd be a lot of typing)